# SQL Query manipulation

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have three tables :

BookingNode , Booking  AirTrip

AirTrip :

```
+----+------------+
| ID |    Name    |
+----+------------+
|  0 | One way    |
|  1 | Round trip |
|  2 | Circle     |
|  3 | Other      |
+----+------------+
```

When ever we make a booking we store the data as :
BookingNode table

```
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------------------+
|   ID   | CustomerGivenName | IPAddress  |        Email         |
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------------------+
| 177022 | xfghfh            | 2130706473 | mikehussey@gmail.com |
| 177021 | cfggjfj           | 2130706473 | mikehussey@gmail.com |
+--------+-------------------+------------+----------------------+
```

Booking Table :

```
+--------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
|   ID   | BookingNodeID | AirTripID | AirLineId  | Provider   |
+--------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
| 181251 |        177020 |         1 |        978 |        Jet |
| 181252 |        177021 |         0 |        982 |         Go |
| 181253 |        177021 |         0 |        978 |        Jet |
+--------+---------------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

If round trip flight is booked and ProviderID is same then a single entry is done in Booking Table with AirTripID value as 1.(Booking ID : 181251 and Provider Jet  )
But if providers are different for both the legs then two entries are done in Booking Table with AirTripID for both entries are one(Booking ID : 181252 and 181253 Provider Go,Jet  ).In this case BookingNodeID  value being same.

Prob : I have to write a query to get different type of Bookings.(Oneway, RoundTrip,Circle).But when I apply join on AirTripID , it is giving me incorrect results.
How can I write my query to give correct results knowing that BookingNodeID is going to be the same for roundtrip (both entries in Booking Table)

Sample Output

```
+-------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+
| AirTripName | BookingNodeID | CustomerGivenName | IPAddress  |
+-------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+
| TwoWay      |        177020 | xfghfh            | 2130706473 |
| TwoWay      |        177021 | cfggjfj           | 2130706473 |
+-------------+---------------+-------------------+------------+
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically, this code might have an error due to my laziness syntom of data entry. But, the logic of the query is, if b.AirTripID is 0, add extra condition which group by Booking. if result return more than 1 row, is actually 2 way. so AirTripType will become 1, otherwise, remain the same as b.AirTripID. You may copy below on and try fix if theres any error. i believe the logic should work based on your expected result.

```
  select 
  bd.ID,
  bd.CustomerGivenName,
  case b.AirTripID 
  when 1 then 1
  when 2 then 2
  when 3 then 3
  when 0 then
    case select BookingNodeID 
    from Booking 
    where Booking.BookingNodeID = bd.ID group by BookingNodeID having Count(BookingNodeID) 
    when 1 then 1 
    else 0 end as AirTripType,
  bd.IPAddress
  from BookingNode bd
  inner join (select BookingNodeID ,AirTripID  from Booking group by BookingNodeID ,AirTripID) as b on b.BookingNodeID = bd.ID
  where id=177021
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
WITH CTE
AS
(
SELECT
    SeqNo = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY BN.ID ORDER BY B.ID),
    B.BookingNodeID,
    BN.CustomerGivenName,
    BN.IPAddress,
    AirTripId = A.ID,
    AirTripNm = A.Name
    FROM Booking B
      INNER JOIN AirTrip A
        ON A.ID = B.AirTripID
      LEFT JOIN BookingNode BN
        ON B.BookingNodeID = BN.id
)
SELECT
  C1.SeqNo,
  AirTripName = CASE WHEN C2.SeqNo IS NOT NULL
                        THEN 'Round trip'
                     ELSE C1.AirTripNm END,
  C1.BookingNodeID,
  C1.CustomerGivenName,
  C1.IPAddress
  FROM CTE C1
    LEFT JOIN CTE C2
      ON C1.BookingNodeID = C2.BookingNodeID
        AND C2.SeqNo = 2
    WHERE c1.SeqNo = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle Link Here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/09836/7)

Answer (score 0):

```
Select  distinct bk.bookingnodeid,cst.customername,ipaddress,
case when count(airtripid)over(partition by bookingnodeid order by bookingnodeid)=2  then 'RoundTrip' else name end As AirTripName
from booking bk
inner join airlinetrip at
on bk.airtripid=at.id
inner join customer cst
on cst.id=bk.bookingnodeid
```